# php echo not displaying

Tags: php, joomla, echo

This should be a simple problem but maybe it's me that simple instead. I have the following code:

```
<?php $county = $_POST['county']; ?>
<?php $cf_id = $_POST['cf_id']; ?>

<h2><strong>County: <?php echo $county; ?><strong></h2>

<input type="hidden" name="county" value="<?php echo $county; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="cf_id" value="<?php echo $cf_id; ?>" />
```

When the page is rendered, $county is not displayed as part of the heading but when I view the page source it is in the hidden field. The static text, "County:" is being displayed.

I have tried various syntaxes (e.g.  and putting all the tags inside a string and then trying to display the string) but haven't hit on the solution.

The code is part of a chronoforms page in joomla. I am aware that Joomla will sometimes remove html but don't believe this is a cause.

This is php version 5.3.20 and joomla 2.5.14. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: First at check, check that $_POST is containing the county var; en second and the main one "use a serious cms"

Comment: Are you sure that $_POST['county'] is not null.. ?

Comment: try: `$county = isset($_POST['county']) ? $_POST['county'] : 'COUNTY_BLANK';`

Comment: ^^ He said he sees it in the <h2> no?  Looks good.  OP that EXACTLY as you have it on your script?  Not seeing an issue.

Comment: Don't forget to use Joomla coding standards for your `post` methods. Joomla doesn't use `$_POST`

Comment: Please use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) to prevent XSS.

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-Top_10

Answer (score 1):

Using Joomla coding standards:

```
$input = new JInput;
$post = $input->getArray($_POST);

if (isset($post["country"])) {
  // do something
}
if (isset($post["cf_id"])) {
  // do something
}
```

Be sure you have Magic Quotes turned **off** when using `JInput`.

Even though the core components still use`JRequest`, it has been deprecated as of Joomla 2.5

Comment: I changed my code and the result is null. I left the other code in the script and the hidden field is still getting populated. I appreciate the help ... I'm really perplexed.

Answer (score 0):

first check $_POST['county'] is set with a value or not

```
if(isset($_POST['county']))
{
echo $_POST['county']; // print $_POST['county']
}
```

Comment: As expected after using the suggestion above, nothing printed since it is null.

Comment: may be you need to follow the coding standards of joomla

Comment: I agree and I changed it to syntax noted by Lodder. I also verified that the method is "post". Also noted that the url contains the county: .../index.php?chronoform=lwg_2014_input_form&option=com_chronoforms&county=Blount

Comment: its not a solutions but once try like this <h2><strong>County: <?=$county; ?></strong></h2>

Comment: I tried that previously but to be sure I tried it again. No joy.

Answer (score 0):

try

> ```
> var_export($_POST['county']);
> ```

it always print result or error/warning about existing var/index if reporting error turn on. I think your **$county is empty**

try `$county = JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('county');`

Comment: `this varian for 1.5` >> well the OP has stated they're using Joomla 2.5

Comment: Using var_export the html generated shows null: "<h2><strong>County: NULL<strong></h2>"
However, the hidden field shows the correct value: "<input type="hidden" name="county" value="Benton"  />"

Answer (score 0):

A solution has been found! The winning entry was CreatoR. His method for getting the data worked for both the hidden field and the display of the text in the heading tag. The final code is:

```
<?php $county = JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('county'); ?>

<input type="hidden" name="county" value="<?php echo $county; ?>" />

<h2><strong>County: <?php echo $county; ?><strong></h2>
```

Thank you to everyone who provided things for me to try and especially to CreatoR for his suggestion. (I would still like to know why the other solutions would work in one line and not in another. Baffling!)